# Is $(0,1)$ homotopic to $(0,1) \times (0,1)$?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Is there a homotopy between a map with $(0,1) \in R^2$ as image and one with $(0,1) \times (0,1)\in R^2$ as image? Both have domain $(0,1)$.
Or the same question for closed intervals.

Comment: Do you mean $(0,1)$ to be the *line*" in $\Bbb R^2$ and $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ to be the square?

Comment: Usually a homotopy is a map such that at time $0$ it is one space, and at time $1$ gives another space, and the whole map is continuous.

Comment: Yes to everything

Comment: Both the interval and the square are contractible, so they are both homotopic to a point.

Comment: what's the ambient space ?

Comment: well then $R^2$ is contractible so for any space $X$ and any two maps $f,g : X \to R^2$, $f$ and $g$ are homotopic.

Comment: This question has changed a lot, previously it was about homotopies and now changed to homeomorphisms. There can't be a homeomorphism since removing an interior point of the interval separates it.

Comment: A refinement, the essence is the same

Comment: Not just a refinement, a different question (with different answer).

Comment: Why would they? A space-filling curve is a continuous surjection $(0,1) \to (0,1)^2$. Is a continuous surjection always a homeomorphism...?

Comment: An improvement in any case. My intuition says it should be

Comment: Do not fundamentally alter your question, and especially, do not deface your question.

Comment: I think that depends on which topology you use. You can probably select a topology that make them homotopic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$

> Why doesnt spacefilling curves imply there is a homeomorphism between $(0, 1) \subset \Reals^{2}$ and $(0, 1) \times (0, 1) \subset \Reals^{2}$?

If there were a *bijective* (continuous) space-filling curve from $X = [0, 1]$ to $Y = [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$, then $X$ and $Y$ would be homeomorphic. (With the open interval and open rectangle, you have to work harder, because a continuous bijection from $(0, 1)$ is not generally a homeomorphism.)

Since an interval (open or closed) is not homeomorphic to a square (open or closed) for other reasons, there exists no bijective continuous map $I \to I \times I$ for $I = [0, 1]$ or $I = (0, 1)$.

Comment: Assuming you mean "homotopy", rather than "homeomorphism", I think this is a good answer for the *closed* sets, but I don't know that it works for the *open* sets.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: It turned out the wording of the question got changed several times while I was typing.... :S (For open sets, if $f:(0, 1) \to (0, 1) \times (0, 1)$ were a continuous bijection, the image of each compact subinterval would be homeomorphic to an interval, hence nowhere-dense. Since $(0, 1)$ is countably exhausted by compact intervals, existence of $f$ would (with a tiny bit of work) contradict the Baire category theorem.)